# Forward call to another MS bot

Tags: botframework

I want to forward activity from one MS Bot in C# (Bot1) to another MS Bot in C# (Bot2). 
For example on some point Bot1 decide that all conversation should go to Bot2.
So Bot2 is able to respond to all questions coming from Bot1 and answer goes to caller who is talking with Bot1.

How it can be achieved? Can you provide examples please.

Comment: I have the same question. I have achieved going to separate LUIS and QnA Maker models, but what I would really like to do is have independently created bots (with their own bot, dialog, and helper files) and have a master orchestration bot that could direct users to a specific bot, and then user could "exit" back to the main bot. I could accomplish something similar with looping dialogs but it seems it would be easier if I could transfer between bots.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the Virtual Assistant's Skills? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-skills-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0